# Unresolved variable WebStorm this.props

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I use WebStorm for React JS and I'm getting this 'Unresolved variable warning' for all props.

I searched for solution everywhere but couldn't find. Whenever i pass down prop value and then use it as this.props.something, that something is unresolved. App works fine and there is no problem, it's just that WebStorm makes this irritating. I installed typescript definitions and nothing.

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class A extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <button>
                {this.props.something}
            </button>
        );
    }
}

class B extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <A something={1}/>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <B/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is screenshot of that:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifopx.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-31785](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31785) for updates

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save @types/react
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

use es6 destructuring to remove the warnings:

eg : rather than

```js
if (this.props.variableName) ...
```

use

```js
const { variableName } = this.props;
if (variableName) ...
```